# How do you ignore uppercase from the input you read from the user

Tags: string

```
String a = keyboard.nextLine().ignoreUpperCase()
```

is this a valid line?

Comment: Not generally no; but some language somewhere might do that. In general though, that sort of very specific question isn't a good fit for the site.

Comment: You probably want toLowerCase() and then compare against lower case strings or vise-versa for upper case

Comment: String a = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase() like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Ignore uppercase"? Please specify the language as well.

Comment: You want to *filter out* upper-case chars, or treat them the same as lower-case chars?

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your intention. The code you shared isn't clear about what you intend to do with the line you are reading from the keyboard.

Like it already has been suggested you could, in Java:

```
String a = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

or

```
String a = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

The intention here is that all lines you are getting are in upper or lower case. Ok if you want to treat all Strings you read from the keyboard as equals regardless of capitalization.

If your real intention is to match strings regardless of case, then the code reads better as:

```
String a = "Hello World";
a.equalsIgnoreCase("hello world");
```

now future maintainers of your code will understand what you're trying to do instead of trying to guess why you are converting to lower/upper case.